# Big array in "$in" query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have to update multiple documents based on array of data.
There are two ways.

1. Loop through data and make X (more then 500) distinct calls of update.
2. Make one call with bloated query like
   `{name:{$in:[/^name1/,/^name2/......,/^name500/]}`

I honestly can't find any "best practice" for this case. Personally I like the second option more, but I am afraid that it will be a bottleneck.

Comment: Why do you think the second case will be a bottleneck? Have you tried it, and found it slow in practice?

Comment: Never tested it. I think (from my SQL experience) that having giant query can be bad for database. But - I am not sure.